# How should i separate production and dev connection settings

Tags: java, security, properties, database-connection, environment-variables

I have an application which I am working on which will eventually of course need a development and production environment. The key is the database connection settings which obviously I want to separate.

What is the correct process for separating these setting so that I don't deploy to production with the dev setting and visa versa so i don't deploy to dev with the production settings.

I was thinking potentially a properties file which is prefixed with prod and dev but I am not sure how robust that approach might be?

Thanks

**To extend the questions a little further**

Based on one of the comments i have looked in to the maven solution, as we are using open shift - there is already some pre-generated pom.xml code which looks as follows;

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the openshift profile will be used when invoking 
                mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the deployments 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>TomcatHotOrNot</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>TomcatHotOrNot</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

So based on the answer provided [Using Maven for multiple deployment environment (production/development)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development) - how would this need to be adapted to follow the solution there?

Thanks

Comment: If you use Maven, you can easily create different profiles for development and production, that use different properties.

Comment: There are several approaches. Using Ant over here, we have folders for separate deployment targets (e.g. local/test/prod) and the config files in these folders take precedence over other deployed files with the same name. Properties can be read from a relatively addressed file (of any type) then.

Comment: @Kayaman I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: You'd want to duplicate that profile to something like openshift-dev and configure what you wish accordingly. Then choose the profile during build time. Refer to maven documentation for the details.