# Jenkins building for different environments

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I currently have a Jenkins instance installed on a Development box. This builds fine and deploys to our development environment without any issues.

During the build process my project makes use of a single properties file containing details such as a database connection URL (Details such as these will obviously vary depending on the environment I'm pointing to).

What I would like to know is what is the best way to configure my project so that when I want to release to Production the WAR file built by Jenkins contains the Production properties instead of Development?

(Note I am also using Maven in my project).

Comment: Couple of useful links.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development -and- http://www.coderanch.com/t/594569/tools/Maven-deploy-war-environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different maven profiles, like `dev`, `prod`, then in the profile setting, use/filter the corresponding resource files like `.../(dev|test|prod)/project.properties` And in Jenkins, when you build for different platform, build with `-Pdev or -Pprod` to get the war for the right target.

You may want to check maven profile, maven resource filtering for detailed configuration.

something not related, connect Database via jndi if possible.

Comment: Just gave this a try and created two different profiles as suggested. Looks good so far, thanks!

Comment: Just a tip: be aware that you cannot use the release-plugin anymore if you use profiles

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just had more concern, if I now build my project on Jenkins it will package the correct properties file. However, it will also auto-deploy to JBoss which I don't want (since it has Production properties). Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: You need two jenkins-jobs, one for the dev-profile and one for the prod-profile. the dev-profile could be the ci-build

Answer (score 2):

I know 3 options:

1. We have used maven.-profiles for that in the past, but they have the disadvantage, that the release-plugin of maven doesn't work with profiles, so we had to change the versions manually and were unable to deploy the artifacts in a remote repository like nexus.
2. Another Option is mavens assembly-plugin. That can be used together with the release-plugin, as far as I know.
3. We decided to write a simple tool that changes the war-files after the maven-build process. It runs in a seperate Jenkins-Job. The Idea is, that building and configuring are two seperate steps. The Artifacts comming out of maven are always in a default-configuration. And if we need the configuration for the production release we start a jenkins job that does the configuration of the war-files.