# Code and DB Automation Migration Tool

Tags: automation, migration

Does someone know of a Code/DB migration tool.  I'm looking for a script-able way of automating code pushes from Dev to Production environments.   The tool should be language/db agnostic so it can work with multiple DB's and development languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this tools (for deployment):

- [Capistrano](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html) + [best practices](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/best-practices.html)
- [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development)
- [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)

In case you are talking about binaries, such concept is **strongly** recommended by the [Continuous delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). Since they consider it as antipattern to promote at the source-code level rather than at the binary level. Use of CI tools to trigger production deployments or you could easily write a simple interface to drive your deploy scripts. Alternatively there are numerous tools available (open source as well as enterprise) which can be used to drive your deployments. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is quite popular.