# When using Maven, how can I separate variables for local/dev/production?

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration

I'd like to have a single maven build that will produce an artifact that can be used on a local machine, our dev environment, staging environment, or production. Since we're talking about production, this means that my db credentials can't be in the artifact anywhere.

This is a Spring app where we're using Maven resource filtering and profiles (`local`, `dev`, `stage`, `prod`) to filter properties in an application.properties file and other files (email templates, etc). So we basically have to build a separate artifact for each environment.

We have been able to get the db passwords out of the pom by using the 
`@PropertySource` annotation but it still seems like we're missing something as this must be a common problem.

I've been able to find [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development) but the answers all seem to have a problem or two - most common of which is having sensitive properties for production in the artifact.

Comment: I think the linked question really does give you the answer you need. What is the problem with that answer in your case?

Comment: The answer for that question sounds pretty good but there are still credentials located in the artifact. I'm now looking into a combination of that solution and the way we've used the `@PropertySource` annotation to get credentials out of the artifacts.

Comment: the properties will end up somewhere in the end. What I would suggest ist creating the deployable artifact without the properties file, but reference one that points to an environment variable/env.properties. Then creating a zip file per environment containing that properties file. Then deploy the artifact and its correct config. This way the config is outside the artifact. This can also be applied to logging configuration since spring also allows to dynamically reload logging configs if changed.