# Managing environment specific configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a spring-boot web app. which has multiple application.properties files for each environment to which it will be deployed; dev1-3, st1-3, uat1-5, prd & psup. I am configuring this by using the "spring.config.location" property. Each application.properties file has an associated spring.profile.active which drives the java config @Configuration using @Profile annotation.

My concern is that all the Java classes to support the environments gets deployed to one common war. So in prod for example I will get the dev1 Java config and classes, it should be "dormant" but I'd be more comfortable if it wasn't there at all. Is there a better way to manage environment configuration?

Comment: a solution would be to organize each profile files in a package, and to config your maven package to exclude the another packages according to the right profile

Comment: Just spotted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development which supports what I'm doing. Appreciate your answer addresses my concern