# Trying to set up different profiles in Spring & Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I need to set up different profiles in my spring app in which I'm using hibernate to allow me to switch from different environments (Dev/Test/PRD).
Below you have 
The issue that I have is that once I create all my properties files, classes and set up the settings. the application crash.
Below you have the dev properties file:

```
profile.name=dev.profiles
# Database Properties
db.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.connectionURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/granojo_db
db.username=root
# db.password=dev_pss
```

And then the dev class:

```
@Component
public class DevEnv implements GenericEnv {

    private String envName = "dev";

    @Value("${profile.name}")
    private String profileName;

    public String getEnvName() {
        return envName;
    }

    public void setEnvName(String envName) {
        this.envName = envName;
    }

    public String getProfileName() {
        return profileName;
    }

    public void setProfileName(String profileName) {
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DevEnv [envName=" + envName + ", profileName=" + profileName
                + "]";
    }
}
```

This is my working spring-config.xml (without any change)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.granojo.controller" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/granojo_db" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Category</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Role</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Status</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Subcategory</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.User</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Video</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Menu</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Watches</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Image</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Program</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Seasson</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Advertisement</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Sponsor</value>
                <value>com.granojo.model.Content</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="categoryService" class="com.granojo.services.CategoryServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="categoryDao" class="com.granojo.dao.CategoryDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="subcategoryService" class="com.granojo.services.SubcategoryServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="subcategoryDao" class="com.granojo.dao.SubcategoryDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="videoService" class="com.granojo.services.VideoServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="videoDao" class="com.granojo.dao.VideoDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="menuService" class="com.granojo.services.MenuServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="menuDao" class="com.granojo.dao.MenuDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="programService" class="com.granojo.services.ProgramServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="programDao" class="com.granojo.dao.ProgramDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="seassonService" class="com.granojo.services.SeassonServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="seassonDao" class="com.granojo.dao.SeassonDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userService" class="com.granojo.services.UserServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.granojo.dao.UserDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="advertisementService" class="com.granojo.services.AdvertisementServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="advertisementDao" class="com.granojo.dao.AdvertisementDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="roleService" class="com.granojo.services.RoleServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="roleDao" class="com.granojo.dao.RoleDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="sponsorService" class="com.granojo.services.SponsorServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="sponsorDao" class="com.granojo.dao.SponsorDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="watchesDao" class="com.granojo.dao.WatchesDaoImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="9999990000000"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jwtTokenAuthFilter" class="com.granojo.security.JWTTokenAuthFilter" />       
</beans>
```

When I remove the dataSource bean(because now I want it to be dynamic) and added the following:

```
<beans profile="dev">
        <!-- allows for ${} replacement in the spring xml configuration from the 
            application-default.properties, application-dev files on the classpath -->
        <context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:properties/application-default.properties, classpath:properties/application-dev.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />

        <!-- scans for annotated classes in the com.env.dev package -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.granojo.conf.DevEnv" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="test">
        <!-- allows for ${} replacement in the spring xml configuration from the 
            application-default.properties, application-test files on the classpath -->
        <context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:properties/application-default.properties, classpath:properties/application-test.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />

        <!-- scans for annotated classes in the com.env.test package -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.granojo.conf.TestEnv" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <!-- allows for ${} replacement in the spring xml configuration from the 
            application-default.properties, application-prod files on the classpath -->
        <context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:properties/application-default.properties, classpath:properties/application-prod.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />

        <!-- scans for annotated classes in the com.env.prod package -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.granojo.conf.ProdEnv" />
    </beans>
```

The application crash because it doesn't find the dataSoruce bean when trying to define the annotated classes.

My questions:
1 - How can I fix this? I want to use different profiles without breaking anything :)
2 - How can I build the app for test and for production using maven? Should I use an specific command or I should include something in the pom.

UPDATE:

I add the following to mu pom.xml

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/properties/default</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/properties/test</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/properties/default</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/properties/dev</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And with this, I can choose which profile to use... But I didn't make any change in my spring-config.xml because if I take something there it break the connection with the hibernate. So the application keep using the config I have in that xml instead the one in the profile.

So in conclusion, I need to remove the datasource information in my spring-config.xml and also the information about the sessionFactory and the annotatedClasses... Because they are all related. So I need to find a way to replace all that so I can take the information from my pom.xml

Comment: You are mixing XML configuration with Annotated configuration. Not easy to find the error.

Comment: Yeah I know :( newbwy mistake.. How can I do it using just one way?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer !!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511414/4287445

You can use maven to do profiling using.

Comment: I tried that and I looks to be what I looking for... But If I follow this, I need to remove the hibernate connectation from my sprint-context.xml and when I do that the sessionFactory is not defined and the autowired of classes are not working which produce a fail when starting the server... How can I remove all this without impacting the functionality?

Comment: can you post your new changes ?

Comment: please post your answer !! so it would be helpful for others in future !!

Comment: I didn't get it working...The done was about to add the information you asked. I change the pom.xml, but I still need to figure out how to implemente the working solution. Now, when I change the spring-config.xml the app crash! So I'm asking for help about how to updated that file to make reference to the pom without breaking anything