# pick environment specific configuration xml in maven build

Tags: java, spring, maven

i have a web application using spring framework and using maven to build war files.

i have to environment specific configuration files. i want to configure maven to pick up the specific configuration file while building a war. as of now, i have to do the environment related changes manually but that's something error prone.

I know there is a environment tag in pom.xml where i can specify the environment but so far i found example of picking up properties file using that, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development).

Please help me with automating this part.

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml and highlight which items you wanted separately in each environment ?

Comment: As the post you linked says, it's best not to have to rebuild the artifact for each env, but to keep the configs outside. If you still want to do it your way, you can use different Maven profiles for each env and configure the resources plugin differently in each profile.

Comment: Don't fall into trap of Maven profile per environment. Make your builds environment agnostic. I gave a talk once about it, maybe slides will be helpful for you: https://speakerdeck.com/maciejwalkowiak/environment-agnostic-applications-with-spring