# How to call Environment specific app.properties using VSTS in Maven build template

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am configuring build pipeline for java api using VSTS with Maven build template. how to configure environment specific configuration (i.e., Dev,QA,Staging... app.properties).

Thanks
Girish

Answer (score 0):

You can use `profiles` to build and package artifacts configured for specific environments. See [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) for details.

Once the build definition is created, we will configure the Maven task to give the path to `pom.xml` so build definition can use `pom.xml`, to compile the source code and create a package file.

Please refer to [Configuration of continuous build integration in VSTS](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/networking_and_servers/9781787127029/3/ch03lvl1sec22/configuration-of-continuous-build-integration-in-vsts) for details.

Another similar thread for your reference: [Using Maven for multiple deployment environment (production/development)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149352/using-maven-for-multiple-deployment-environment-production-development)

Comment: I have created the profiles as shown in above link. But I am not sure how to run the specified command to fetch corresponding properties file in maven VSTS build component.